# Angularjs basic filtering works as union instead of intersection

Tags: angularjs, filter

I've got quite simple html table which I want to filter using several input fields. Using this structure  I expect that several filled inputs would work as intersection and I'd only see details which much both conditions. But currently it is working as union, so I'am seeing any detail that matches any input text. While reading internets I saw that most people had backward problem - when similar code worked as intersection. So I am lost which behaviour is expected by default and what would the correct way to solve my task.

HTML (I am using first 4 inputs for filtering and have no special code for filtering in js part):

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ItemController as ItemCtrl">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText.$">
<input type="text" placeholder="SubmittedBy" ng-model="searchText.fields.submitted_by">
<input type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="searchText.fields.description">
<input type="text" placeholder="Responsible" ng-model="searchText.fields.responsible">

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tickets">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-change="checkAll()" /></th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>SubmittedBy</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Responsible</th>
            <th>DateToFix</th>
            <th>DateFound</th>
            <th>Fixed</th>
            <th>DateFixed</th>
            <th>Confirmed</th>
            <th>DateConfirmed</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:(searchText||undefined)" id="{[{item.pk}]}" class="base" ng-class="{'info' : item.fields.fixed && !item.fields.confirmed, 'success' : item.fields.confirmed}">
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected"></td>
            <td>{[{item.pk}]}</td>
            <td>{[{item.fields.submitted_by}]}</td>
            <td>{[{item.fields.description}]}</td>
            <td>{[{item.fields.responsible}]}</td>
            <td>{[{item.fields.date_to_fix | date:'EEEE, MMM d, y'}]}</td>
            <td>{[{item.fields.date_found | date:'EEEE, MMM d, y HH:mm:ss'}]}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.fields.fixed" ng-change="ItemCtrl.fix(item.pk, item.fields.fixed)"></td>
            <td>{[{item.fields.date_fixed | date:'EEEE, MMM d, y HH:mm:ss'}]}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.fields.confirmed" ng-change="ItemCtrl.confirm(item.pk, item.fields.confirmed)"></td>
            <td>{[{item.fields.date_fix_confirmed | date:'EEEE, MMM d, y HH:mm:ss'}]}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I don't think that data I get from server is relevant here, but if needed I'll post it here. Considering:

> (searchText||undefined)

I was using it for filtering columns with checkboxes (all, checked, non-checked) and with or without "undefined" is is working the same.

Here is there plunker link for my example: http://plnkr.co/edit/22M3Nsl36OAK2aLrJz6T?p=info
I've discovered that my issue dissappeares as soon as I exclude "fields" dict from "data" and use values likes this:

```
        <td>{{item.submitted_by}}</td>
        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
        <td>{{item.responsible}}</td>
```

but that's what I wouldn't like to do since I'll have to change it on server side.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or a runnable code snippet that replicates the problem?

Comment: @bmleite I've placed it in the text of my question, also found a reason for that behaviour, but can't work it around at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a search expression with nested objects, Angular will return in the filtered list **all items that match with at least one** of the properties from those nested objects.

For example, if you have a search object like this:

```
{
  fields: {
    propA: 'bananas',
    propB: 'apples'
  }
}
```

And an object like this in the items list:

```
{
  fields: {
    propA: 'orange',
    propB: 'apples'
  }
}
```

That object will be returned by the filter as a match (despite `fields.propA` don't match).

Since it is not documented, I'm not sure if this is the expected behaviour or a possible bug. Nevertheless you have a way to avoid this problem, just define your own **comparator**:

```
var comparator = function(actual, expected) {
    if (actual && expected && typeof actual === 'object' && typeof expected === 'object') {
        var res = true;
        for (var key in expected) {
            if (key.charAt(0) !== '$' && hasOwnProperty.call(actual, key)) {
                res = res && comparator(actual[key], expected[key]);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    expected = (''+expected).toLowerCase();
    return (''+actual).toLowerCase().indexOf(expected) > -1;
};
$scope.comparator = comparator;
```

And then on the HTML:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchText:comparator"
```

**[Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bOwpspAtuwdWFVJqwuYd?p=preview)**